# How to get reference to Component from inside an event method

Tags: javascript, helper, component

I have a `JavaScript` helper method which handles a message sent from a child `iframe`

```
handleMessage: function (event) {
    console.log('handleMessage');
    console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.data)));
},
```

The helper method is set during `OnInit`:

```
onInit: function (cmp, event, helper) {
    window.addEventListener("message", $A.getCallback(helper.handleMessage));
},
```

Once a message arrives in `handleMessage` I need a reference to `cmp` or `component` but I do not have it.

**Question**

1. How can I access `cmp` or `component` from inside the `handleMessage` helper method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) it to the function call. You'd want to make the following changes:

```
// Helper function
handleMessage: function (cmp, event) {
    console.log('handleMessage');
    console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.data)));
},

// Main code
onInit: function (cmp, event, helper) {
    window.addEventListener("message", $A.getCallback(helper.handleMessage.bind(helper, cmp)));
},
```